# Not able to write data in xlsx file using java?

Tags: java

I Have a data stored in variables and then i want to write my data to excel file(.xlsx). 
(i.e) I use automation testing tools like selenium to get data from webpage and i store it in variable which i want to wrie in xlsx file

After a lot of google search I found many of users uses list or objects to write into .xlsx file.

I created a list and add my variable to that list and using looping statements (for loop) i checked whether my data is stored in list by printing it.

Then I created *XSSFWorkbook* and *XSSFSheet* and *XSSFRow* and *XSSFCell* to write data.
I write a cell by using ***setCellValue*** method to my cell.

My code successfully creates a xlsx file and sheet in it
but after execution i could not able to find any data in it.

**Source code:**

```
ArrayList<String> head = new ArrayList<String>();

head.add("Register Number");
head.add(subject1);
head.add(subject2);  //subject1 and subject2 are variable i created

System.out.println(head.get(1));  //To check if my list has value

XSSFWorkbook workbook = new XSSFWorkbook();                               
FileOutputStream fileOut = new FileOutputStream("/home/st.xlsx"); 

for (int i = 0; i < head.size(); i++) 

{

     XSSFRow  Row  = sheet1.createRow(1);
     XSSFCell cell = Row.createCell(1);                          
     cell.setCellValue(head.get(1));                             
     sheet1.autoSizeColumn(1);
}

workbook.write(fileOut);
fileOut.close();
```

I expect my code add data to my file.

Main thing is ***During execution when i try to open my .xlsx file it has data in it.***

But after the ***complete execution i get with the empty xlsx file.***

I don't know why i'm getting this and What wrong in my code?

Thanks in advance!

Comment: I think you want head.get(0)

Comment: This code doesn't reference Selenium so I removed those tags. You will want to add a tag for the Java/Excel library that you are using to get help from those folks too.

Comment: Would you be kind enough to wrap your code in a standalone example, a [SSCCE](http://www.sscce.org/)? That way we can plop the code into Eclipse or whatever and run it without needing to write a `main` and such. Of course, it's understood that we need to include the POI library.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
ArrayList<String> head = new ArrayList<String>();

head.add("Register Number");
head.add(subject1);
head.add(subject2);  // subject1 and subject2 are variable i created

System.out.println(head.get(0));  // To check if my list has value
System.out.println(head.get(1));  // To check if my list has value
System.out.println(head.get(2));  // To check if my list has value

XSSFWorkbook workbook = new XSSFWorkbook();                               
XSSFSheet sheet1 = wb.createSheet("Sheet1");

for (int r = 0; r < head.size(); r++) 
{

     XSSFRow row  = sheet1.createRow(r);
     XSSFCell cell = row.createCell(0);                          
     cell.setCellValue(head.get(r));                             
     sheet1.autoSizeColumn(0);
}

// Write this workbook to a FileOutputStream.
FileOutputStream fileOut = new FileOutputStream("/home/st.xlsx"); 
workbook.write(fileOut);
fileOut.flush();
fileOut.close();
```

More info here:
https://gist.github.com/madan712/3912272